# replace &nbsp; with a regex

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Hi everyone i was trying to compile a regex to replace `&nbsp;` with a space from a string such as `<p>{{Today's&nbsp;&nbsp; Date}}</p>`

How do I replace   inside a string within double Curley braces {{}}.

any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: In your example there is already a space after the "&nbsp;". Is that expected or just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the `&nbsp;`  parts (including the whitespace) that are inside curly braces. I would suggest using capture groups. In general, capture groups are implemented with parenthesis "(" ")". For your case, if you are using Java it will look like

```
        String a = "<p>{{Today's&nbsp;&nbsp; </x>Date}}</p>";

        //first (.*) would be the first capture group
        //(\\&nbsp; )+ would be the second capture group
        //second (.*) would be the third capture group
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.*)(\\&nbsp; )+(.*)\\}\\}");
        
        Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
        
        String result = m.replaceAll("$1 $3");//$n refers to the nth capture group
        
        System.out.println(result);
```

And the result would be

```
<p>Today's&nbsp; Date</p>
```

For regex testing I recommend using this online tool
https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html